# Getting the facebook graph to only return results with a # symbol in it

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hashtag

Any one have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I have tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22%23apple%22
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23apple
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q#apple
```

which does not work.

To be clear the results should only have posts that contain #apple not "apple".

Comment: the second one works for me

Comment: None of the results in the second one return #apple, they return just apple.

Comment: do you have an example of some post or something you expect it to find ? (the id would help)

Comment: Use - https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%2326acts 

It returns posts that have #26acts and without the #. We want to be able to return only posts that match "#26acts"

post id example - 107030249319841_100393446801425

Comment: It seems facebook ignores that # but I can't find it documented anywhere

Comment: Yeah, we are trying to find a work around outside of harassing FB to add the feature in.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook says this is not supported at this time: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/313941462054417/

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to get the #hashtags from Facebook, currently, there is no api for this. and even if there were- the posts are not intermediate, they are being cached. you won't see the most recent hashtag from a person who's not in your friendlist right away, this will take a long time to appear in the hashtag search

Answer (score 0):

I've read too that it's not supported but,

trying the second line of jlarry

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23apple
```

in *Graph API Explorer*, it works. 
obviously the query is on the posts set as public.

so the query could be something like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23joviberton‬&type=post
```

for further ops check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/